# Electron - GPU is not used and frame rate is low in the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, hardware-acceleration

While developing my app, I encouraged a not-to-solve problem. After adding lots of data to the scroll area (lots of divs with images and text), the app starts lagging. I've tested performance in devtools and FPS vary between 15 - 20, after adding one `position: fixed` element - between 0 - 1 :D

However, when I check Windows Task Manager, I can't see if Electron uses GPU anytime, while Discord or Firefox uses (e.g when scrolling). And I think here's the rub. How can I enable GPU acceleration on Electron and/or how can I optimize my app to run with lots of DIV elements at 60fps?

Comment: can you add the command with attributes you use to start the electron application?